# How to hijack a key assignment to raise an event that triggers its event handler?

Tags: pstricks, key-value

Whenever I invoke `\degrees` the definition of operator `au` (angle unit) will be updated. It is easily done by redefining the `\degrees` with `\let` and `\renewcommand`. So far so good.

Now I want to create two more operators `pt2xu` and `pt2yu` which convert `pt` (point) to the active unit in both `x` and `y` direction.
Unfortunately, the active unit `\psxunit` and `\psyunit` must be updated via key-value assignment so I cannot apply my method with `\let` and `\renewcommand` here. Instead I have to create a new macro called `\updateoperator`. This `\updateoperator` must be invoked at least once for initialization. The subsequent invocation must be done after we make assignment to `unit`, `xunit` and `yunit`. It is a bad idea to have such an interface as the users might forgot to invoke `\updateoperator` after doing assignment.

My idea is to hijack `unit`, `xunit` and `yunit` assigment such that they silently invoke `\updateoperator` at least one for initialization and when they are updated via key-value assignment.

Do you  have any idea to implement it?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\makeatletter

\let\tempdegrees\degrees
\renewcommand\degrees[1][360]{\pstVerb{/au {\pst@angleunit} bind def}\tempdegrees[#1]}

\def\updateoperator{\pstVerb{/pt2xu {\pst@number\psxunit div} bind def /pt2yu {\pst@number\psyunit div} bind def}}

\makeatother
\updateoperator% the first invocation for initialization
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,0)(4,2)
    \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=20pt](2,0)(2,1)
    \psframe*[linecolor=blue](!2 10 pt2yu sub 1)(!2 10 pt2yu add 2)
    \qdisk(!1 90 PtoC){1}
\end{pspicture}

\psset{unit=2cm,runit=2cm}
\updateoperator
\degrees[400]

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-.5,0)(2,1)
    \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=20pt](1,0)(1,.5)
    \psframe*[linecolor=blue](!1 10 pt2yu sub .5)(!1 10 pt2yu add 1)
    \qdisk(!.5 100 au PtoC){.5}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to the keyword `unit` is handled by the macro `\psset@pstricks@unit`. Thus you can hijack the processing  of the argument by writing (in a context where `@` is a letter, e.g. within a package file):

```
\let\saved@pstricks@unit=\psset@pstricks@unit
\def\psset@pstricks@unit#1{%
  \saved@pstricks@unit{#1}%
  \updateoperator
}
```

The behaviour of the `unit` keyword is defined in `pstricks.tex` by the following snippet:

```
\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{unit}[1cm]{%
  \pssetlength\psunit{#1}%
  \psxunit=\psunit%
  \psyunit=\psunit%
}
```

If this changes, the synthetised name for the macro `\psset@pstricks@unit` may also change.

A second option could be to hijack the `\psset` macro as in

```
 \let\saved@psset=\psset
 \def\psset#1{\saved@psset{#1}\updateoperator}
```